# MCL Designer - Loop through a record

Tags: loops, mcl

hopefully there's someone here who works with MCL-Designer.

I am using a loop to insert into the db file that goes through the .dat file record by record and inserts it into the database one by one.

The problem is that I have 200 records and this cycle takes 18 seconds on the device, which is a long time.

Does anyone know how to make this process more efficient?

[image]